# Add integers provided by the user, stopping when the user writes "Stop"

Tags: python

> Write a function add_up that adds integers provided by the user, stopping when the user writes "Stop".

I receive an error message stating that my code is not performing the stated function.

```
x = input("First number: ")

def add_up(x):
    Num = 0
    while x != "Stop":
        Num = int(x) + Num
        x = input("Another numer: ")
    return Num

print(add_up(x))
```

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg9de.png)

Comment: An important step, requesting the first number, is outside of the function.

Comment: What specifically is the error?

Comment: you have to give us the exact error message you are getting for us to help you!

Comment: How would I incorporate the first input into the function? Im not sure how to do that without print(add_up(x)). x being any number

Comment: @MichaelMalinowski please tell us what error ur getting

Comment: The error message is external and not within python. The website im using gives an error message if they dont except the code with no feed back as to why its wrong.

Comment: @MichaelMalinowski is it like a problem solving website you are on. If that's the case, it would be helpful if you posted the instructions.

Comment: https://open.cs.uwaterloo.ca/python-from-scratch/8/7/#4 This is the website im using

Comment: Read the first input within the function and outside loop.

Comment: Your code seems to run completely fine. The site indicates there was an error, without extra information. Pythonishly-speaking, I don't see a real problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> def add_up():
...     num = 0
...     while True:
...         x = input("Write a number: ")
...         if x.lower() == 'stop':
...             return num
...         num += int(x)
... 
>>> print(add_up())
Write a number: 1
Write a number: 5
Write a number: 1
Write a number: Stop
7
```